# Application works on wildfly but not on tomcat

Tags: java, wildfly, vaadin, tomcat8, vaadin-flow

I created a Vaadin application and I am able to deploy it on Wildfly, however I am not able to deploy it on Tomcat 8.5. I get the following errors when I try to deploy it on Tomcat:

```
    Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CQT-2' did not find a matching property.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 31 2016 19:51:16 UTC
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.5.0
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Public\workspace\development\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Public\workspace\development\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Public\workspace\development\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x64;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;D:\Public\software\apache-maven-3.5.4-bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;D:\Public\software\spring\spring-tool-suite-3.9.5.RELEASE-e4.8.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE;;.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 926 ms
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:14 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] from Jar [file:/D:/Public/workspace/development/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/CQT-2/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.9.3.jar] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2053)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing AtmosphereFramework
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.vaadin.cdi.CdiServletDeployer - Automatically deploying CDI Vaadin servlet to /*
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer - Skipping automatic servlet registration because there is already a Vaadin servlet with the name com.vaadin.cdi.CdiServletDeployer
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletDeployer - Automatically deploying Vaadin servlet with name frontendFilesServlet to /frontend/*
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: /*
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoConfigureService
INFO: Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.util.ForkJoinPool <init>
INFO: Using ForkJoinPool  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool. Set the org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads to -1 to fully use its power.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework initWebSocket
INFO: Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport <init>
INFO: JSR 356 Mapping path 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptors
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Dropping Interceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor CORS Interceptor Support with priority FIRST_BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Default Response's Headers Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser Padding Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Android Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor SSE Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor JSONP Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser disconnection detection with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Broadcaster Shared List Resources: false
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Shared ExecutorService supported: true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Messaging ExecutorService Pool Size unavailable - Not instance of ThreadPoolExecutor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: HttpSession supported: true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere Framework 2.4.30.vaadin1 started.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: /*
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
INFO: Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoConfigureService
INFO: Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.util.ForkJoinPool <init>
INFO: Using ForkJoinPool  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool. Set the org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads to -1 to fully use its power.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework initWebSocket
INFO: Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport <init>
INFO: JSR 356 Mapping path /frontend
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptors
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Dropping Interceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework newAInterceptor
INFO:   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework configureAtmosphereInterceptor
INFO: Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor CORS Interceptor Support with priority FIRST_BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Default Response's Headers Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser Padding Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Android Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor SSE Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor JSONP Interceptor Support with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser disconnection detection with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Broadcaster Shared List Resources: false
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Shared ExecutorService supported: true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Messaging ExecutorService Pool Size unavailable - Not instance of ThreadPoolExecutor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: HttpSession supported: true
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework info
INFO: Atmosphere Framework 2.4.30.vaadin1 started.
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8085]
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9823 ms
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet com.vaadin.cdi.CdiServletDeployer as unavailable
Mar 05, 2019 9:22:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet com.vaadin.cdi.CdiServletDeployer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this? Thanks.

I am using below libraries, in case it matters:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Composite;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasElement;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Text;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterObserver;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest;
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the stacktrace, the problem is that on Tomcat you get a

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager

The fact that it works on Wildfly but not on Tomcat is due to the fact that Wildfly is an application server already containing lots of libraries (depending on the version you use). The Java EE Full & Web Distribution in Version 16.0.0.Final e.g. contains the libary cdi-api-2.0.SP1.jar (under wildfly-16.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\enterprise\api\main) which contains the BeanManager-class. The class is therefore found and it works.

Tomcat is a web server that doesn't contain EE-Libraries by default. So when deploying to Tomcat you have to ensure that the library containing the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager class is on the class path when deploying to tomcat.

The library that contains that class is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/2.0.SP1 and depending on what kind of project you use you can add a maven/gradle dependency like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.SP1</version>
</dependency>
```

(when using maven) or download the jar-file and put it into your self-managed libraries when not using a build management tool like maven etc.

Comment: I did this and still got the error regarding annotations.

Comment: does that error prevent your application from working? It is hard to say what exactly the problem is out of the box. What Java version did you use to build your application? And which Java version do you use to run the tomcat? I can't say what exactly the problem is but it seems like a Java version related error (see https://blog.doubleslash.de/unable-to-process-jar-entry-module-info-class-from-jar/). Depending on your setup you could try downgrading your byte buddy dependency to 1.8.X instead of 1.9.X because with version 1.9.0 Java 11 support was implemented.

Comment: You are only half right. The "javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0.SP1" jar only provides the standard API classes - it does not provide a CDI implementation. Adding the implementation is not trivial because it would require integration with the Tomcat servlet API implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Applications that run on WildFly, Payara, TomEE, WebSphere, GlassFish, etc are not normally portable to Tomcat. All of these servers provide an implementation of the [Java(™) EE 7 Specification APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/). Newer versions of these servers implement the [Java(TM) EE 8 Specification APIs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/), which include the Servlet 4.0 API.

Tomcat 8.5 only implements the [Servlet 3.1 API - Apache Tomcat 8.5.38](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/index.html). If you look at this and compare it with either of the above you will get an appreciation of just how much is missing from Tomcat.

I believe that TomEE, GlassFish and Payara all contain properly integrated Tomcat components.

Answer (score 0):

Hi As i can see you are getting issue with your jar byte-buddy-1.9.3.jar try removing it from your build path and just go inside your eclipse workspace and paste manually inside the lib folder of your project and after that pls refresh your project. Hope this will rectify your issue.

Comment: I put version 1.9.10, and now I get the same error for this version.

Comment: did u try adding the jar manually by pasting inside your workspace or you have directely added it to buld path